# Is there a way to efficiently index table inheritance in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, table-per-type

I am toying with the idea of moving from a Table Per Hierarchy model to a Table Per Type model.

I haven't been able to find any conclusive material on whether there is an efficient way (from a performance perspective) to do this.

Are there any indexing techniques that can be used to ensure good performance with large datasets in a Table Per Type database model?

Comment: Either model seems like you're letting your code drive your table design, instead of letting good table design drive you code.

Comment: I thought moving to a table per type model is good table design!